# Using sed to extracting data from file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with lines like following:

{u'phone_num': u'9999999999', u'name': u'abc', u'format': u'json'}

I am trying to extract the phone number i.e. 9999999999 from each line.

The sed I am using is not working.

```
echo "{u'phone_num': u'9999999999', u'name': u'abc', u'format': u'json'}" | sed 's/.*phone_num.*\([[:digit:]]\+).*/\1/'
```

This is printing the whole line and not just the digits.

Comment: Why don't use cut? `echo "{u'phone_num': u'9999999999', u'name': u'abc', u'format': u'json'}"| cut -d"'" -f 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed "s/^{u'phone_num':[[:blank:]]*u'\([^']*\).*$/\1/" file
9999999999
```

Comment: Can you please explain? Also, Please let me know why the regex I am using is not working.

Comment: This regex matches `u'phone_num': u'` at the beginning and captures next string into back reference 1. Then in the replacement it uses `\1` to output `9999999999` only.

Comment: Also, What if I need to extract both the name and phone number?

Comment: Thanks for explanation but this is not working when I am trying this:

Comment: I have also attached output being generated from this command. You can also try: `sed "s/.*phone_num.*'\([[:digit:]]*\)'.*/\1/" file`

Comment: Yes. But I still don't understand why my command was not working. Also, for getting both name and phone number I tried this which is not working:  echo "{u'phone_num': u'9999999999', u'name': u'abc', u'format': u'json'}" | sed "s/.*phone_num.*'\([[:digit:]]*\)'.*name.*'\([a-z]*\)'/\1\2/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62660/discussion-between-anuj-and-anubhava).

Comment: Use this sed for getting both phone # and name: **`echo "$s"|sed "s/.*phone_num.*'\([[:digit:]]*\)'.*name': *u'\([^']*\)'.*/\1-\2/"`**

Comment: Is it possible to have \2 as optional reference? I mean if regex is not matching the reference will output blank for \2.

Comment: Hmm better to use gnu-awk in that case: `awk -F ': *' -v RS='[{,}] *' 'NF>1{gsub(/u?'"'"'/, "")} $1~/phone_num|name/{print $2}' file` But I think this is going well beyond original problem. Better post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution using `awk`

`echo "{u'phone_num': u'9999999999', u'name': u'abc', u'format': u'json'}" | awk -F "'" '{ print $4 }'`